# How to get query result if linq to DataTable?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Can any one tell, how to get the result of LINQ query contains group by to DataTable .

```
var query= from d in dtable.AsEnumerable()
           group d by d["Id"];

WId FirstName LastName Age
1   Jass      we       23 
1   Mady      wer      54
3   Servy     gr       22
4   Jan       fr       11

Expected
    WId FirstName LastName Age
    1   Jass      we       23 
    3   Servy     gr       22
    4   Jan       fr       11
```

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What results are you interested in?

Comment: I have some 4 more columns other than Id. I want to read all query result to DataTable.

Comment: Have you tried [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738024)?

Comment: Is there any solution other than looping through the result ?

Comment: Can you write out what you actually expect. `var` doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: Above is the one i am expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to take the first person per ID-Group:

```
var distinctIdPersons = from p in dtable.AsEnumerable()
                        group p by p.Field<int>("WId") into IdGroups
                        select IdGroups.First();
```

or in method syntax:

```
distinctIdPersons = dtable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("WId"))
                                         .Select( g => g.First());
```

If you want to see the result(f.e. for testing purposes), you can use `string.Join`:

```
var output = string.Join(", ", distinctIdPersons.Select(r => 
    r.Field<string>("FirstName") + " " + r.Field<string>("LastName")));
Console.WriteLine(output); // Jass we, Servy gr, Jan fr
```